# Why doesn't Red Hat detect hard drive on HP BL460C Gen 8?

Tags: linux, system-installation, hard-disk, setuptools

EDIT: The server I am using is HP BL460C Gen 8 having real hardware RAID.

I am trying to install Red Hat Enterprise x86_64 bit on an HP ProLiant (iLO 4) server with an Array of 2 hard drives configured as RAID1.

The built in server manager allows me to change the setting and configuration of the storage array between RAID0 and RAID1

But RED HAT starts the process of the clean install, and i get to select the time, language, etc. but it stops because it could not detect a storage disk. All it can see is the virtual boot drive that it creates while booting to allow it to run (capacity 256 MB).

I tried to manually/custom add the storage setting but again, all available storage is 250 mb and all found devices is 1.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of RAID card is it? Is it real hardware RAID or [fakeraid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID#Firmware.2Fdriver-based)?

Comment: Also, what model server (such as DLxxx Gen y)?

Comment: Real Raid and model is (BL460C Gen 8) @MarkPlotnick

Comment: P220i Smart Array controller? You can download driver software from HP at http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=5295173 . I do not have an HP machine to test this on, sorry.

Comment: How can i use the drivers if the OS is not yet installed? @MarkPlotnick

Comment: The Red Hat installation program gives you the option of loading drivers from a separate CD or DVD or USB drive. https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/chap-Updating_drivers_during_installation_on_Intel_and_AMD_systems.html

Comment: It also looks like your server supports Intelligent Provisioning http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/server-software/product-detail.html?oid=5219984#!tab=features  . "Intelligent Provisioning replaces SmartStart CDs and can be accessed during server boot by pressing F10 key to get started. Intelligent Provisioning replaces SmartStart CDs and is embedded on the ProLiant Gen8 server. With Intelligent Provisioning all needed drivers and software tools are pre-loaded onto the server"

Comment: @MarkPlotnick yes, i reconfigured the RAID array using the intelligent provisioning tool, but it still did not work

Comment: Sorry I can't be of more help. You might try asking this question on serverfault.com.